# How do I write a Grammar for post-increment/decrement operators in YACC?

Tags: c, yacc, unary-operator

```
%type <string> Id
%type <ExprRes> Factor
%type <ExprRes> Term
%type <ExprRes> Expr
%type <InstrSeq> StmtSeq
%type <InstrSeq> Stmt
%type <BExprRes> BExpr
%type <ExprRes> Primary

%token Ident        
%token IntLit   
%token Int
%token Write
%token IF
%token EQ
%token GTE
%token LTE
%token UM
%token UP   

%%

Prog            :   Declarations StmtSeq                                {Finish($2); } ;
Declarations    :   Dec Declarations                                    { };
Declarations    :                                                       { };
Dec             :   Int Ident {EnterName(table, yytext, &entry); }';'   { };
StmtSeq         :   Stmt StmtSeq                                        { $$ = AppendSeq($1, $2); } ;
StmtSeq         :                                                       { $$ = NULL;} ;
Stmt            :   Write Expr ';'                                      { $$ = doPrint($2); };
Stmt            :   Id '=' Expr ';'                                     { $$ = doAssign($1, $3);} ;
Stmt            :   IF '(' BExpr ')' '{' StmtSeq '}'                    { $$ = doIf($3, $6);};
BExpr           :   Expr EQ Expr                                        { $$ = doBExpr($1, $3);};
Expr            :   Expr '+' Term                                       { $$ = doAdd($1, $3); } ;
Expr            :   Expr '-' Term                                       { $$ = doMinus($1, $3); };
Expr            :   Term                                                { $$ = $1; } ;
Term            :   Term '*' Factor                                     { $$ = doMult($1, $3); } ;
Term            :   Term '/' Factor                                     { $$ = doDiv($1, $3); } ;
Term            :   Factor                                              { $$ = $1; } ;
Factor          :   Primary                                             { $$ = $1;};
Primary         :   '-'Primary                                              { $$ = doUnaryMinus($1);};

Primary         :   IntLit                                              { $$ = doIntLit(yytext); };
Primary         :   Ident                                               { $$ = doRval(yytext); };
Id              :   Ident                                               { $$ = strdup(yytext);}
```

this is my yacc grammar.  i am trying to get a unary minus to work.  x-- for example.

however when I try to run it on my test file

```
int num1;    
int num2;  
int num3;   
int num4;

num3 = 100;    
num4 = 200;   
num3 = num4 / num3;  
num1 = 1;   
num1 = num3-num1;  
num1--;

print num3;   
print num4;   
print num1;
```

I get a yyerror at the line num1--;

yyerror is incredibly vague in any details I can find about it.  I can only find that it is called when it encounters an error in input.  I dont know whether that error comes from my misunderstanding of how I am supposed to write my grammar, or what.  I have a program that points to the illegal character and it says that the issue is coming from the first '-' symbol in the line.  I would like any ideas on where to look to find my answer or if you see an error.

this is my lex file:

```
%{
#include "yaccExample.h"
#include "y.tab.h"

#define YY_INPUT(buf,result,max_size) \
    { int c = GetSourceChar(); \
          result = (c == EOF) ? YY_NULL : (buf[0] = c, 1); \
        }

%}


letter [A-Za-z]
digit [0-9]

%%
if                              {return IF;}
int                             {return Int;}
print                           {return Write;}
{letter}({letter}|{digit})*     {return Ident;}
{digit}{digit}*                 {return IntLit;}
\=\=                            {return EQ;}
\-\-                            {return UM;}
\+\+                            {return UP;}
\>\=                            {return GTE;}
\<\=                            {return LTE;}
\=                              {return '=';}
\+                              {return '+';}
\*                              {return '*';}
\;                              {return ';';}
\{                              {return '{';}
\}                              {return '}';}
\(                              {return '(';}
\)                              {return ')';}

[ ]                             {}
\t                              {}
\r                              {}
\n                              {}

.               {WriteIndicator(GetCurrentColumn());
                   WriteMessage("Illegal Character in lex");}

%%


yywrap () {
}
```

Comment: why did you include the 'c' tag in your question?

Comment: 'x--' is not a unary minus. '-x' is a unary minus. 'x--' is a post-decrement. Is yyerror() being called from the parser? Or are you calling it yourself from the lexer? The words 'illegal character' suggest the latter, in which case only you can know why you called it.

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer The code inserts in a y file are written in C, or C++. I don't see why he shouldn't tag it as C.

Comment: Your grammar looks correct, but it's expecting the token `UM` for `--`.  What token is your lexer giving you?  Show your `.l` file, or whatever you are using for a lexer.

Comment: The first thing I would check is whether your lexer is actually returning UM and not '-' '-'.

Comment: @EJPwell maybe thats the issue I'm having?  I was just told I needed to implement unary minus. I thought thats what x-- was. Either way i have fixed it to do a proper unary minus and expect a simple '-' character.  however I am Still getting the error on the minus operator

Comment: How do i tell where yyerror is being called from?

Comment: Err, inspect your code? If you're not calling it from the lexer, the generated parser is calling it. What's the error message? Where's your .l file? Where's your current .y file?

Comment: It is called from parser.  the .y  file is up to date and i just added my .l file

Comment: I didnt have my test file set up right.  i have it fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a misunderstanding of terminology. Unary minus means a minus sign alone preceding a primary, as per your grammar.

```
Primary         :   '-'Primary
```

The correct test code for your grammar looks like this. It should compile correctly.

```
num1 = -99;  
num1 = -num3;
num1 = -(num3-num1);
```

The operator '--' is called decrement and does not appear in your grammar. If you need to compile a decrement operator, you will have to add it to your grammar.

Answer (score 0):

yacc has only limited support for debugging your grammar.  One thing that often helps in cases like this is defining the `YYDEBUG` preprocessor symbol and setting the `yydebug` global to non-zero.  This will cause a dump to stdout of all the tokens scanned and shifted and rules reduced while parsing, which can help.

Add:

```
#ifdef YYDEBUG
    extern int yydebug;
    yydebug = 1;
#endif
```

to your main function (or possibly use a command line switch to set `yydebug`), and compile all of your source files with `-DYYDEBUG`